# window.print as direct jquery callback - illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Curious to understand this behavior - using Chrome

`$(selector).click(window.print)` gives 'illegal invocation' error

`$(selector).click(function() { window.print(); })` works

see http://jsfiddle.net/e2LLnj1c/

If `window.print` is a function, why can't I use it as the click callback directly?

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely that the `this` variable of your callback is the DOM node itself, and window.print relies on it being `window` itself.

You could pass in `window.print.bind(window)` to ensure that the `this` variable is set correctly.

JsFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/38yn9kq5/

Comment: This is correct. While `window.print` is a function, but it's crucial for its internal implementation that invocation context (`this` inside) be proper object, `window` global object.

Comment: Bitten again by Javascript - the bad parts.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery calls the handler function using `apply` method on the function object and passing the current element object as `this` object parameter which causes the problem as the `this` should be window object in case of `print` function.